# Is there a way to avoid or resize the big OK button for pop-up dialogs?

Tags: python, interface

I'm trying to create a bit of a minimal pop-up dialog, so it would be great to avoid the big OK button...

[image]

```
import bpy

class WM_OT_myop(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "wm.myop"
    bl_label = "Simple Object Operator"
    name : bpy.props.StringProperty(name="Name", default="")

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object is not None

    def execute(self, context):
        return {'FINISHED'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        wm = context.window_manager
        return wm.invoke_props_dialog(self)

def menu_draw(self, context):
    self.layout.operator("wm.myop")

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(WM_OT_myop)
    bpy.types.TEXT_MT_text.append(menu_draw)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(WM_OT_myop)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # test call
    bpy.ops.wm.myop('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```

Comment: Hello, could you also post the code you used in your example in the question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can you `bpy.context.window_manager.invoke_popup()` instead of `window_manager.invoke_props_dialog()`. That invoke does not have any *Ok* button, it is used for only showing the properties but you can use that for your operations by adding an update function.

````
import bpy
# update function, You can create however you like.
# my update funtion will rename the object name
def object_rename(self,context):
    propery = self.name
    bpy.context.active_object.name = propery
    

class WM_OT_myop(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "wm.myop"
    bl_label = "Simple Object Operator"
    name : bpy.props.StringProperty(name="Name", default="", update=object_rename)

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object is not None

    def execute(self, context):
        return {'FINISHED'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        wm = context.window_manager
        return wm.invoke_popup(self)

def menu_draw(self, context):
    self.layout.operator("wm.myop")

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(WM_OT_myop)
    bpy.types.TEXT_MT_text.append(menu_draw)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(WM_OT_myop)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # test call
    bpy.ops.wm.myop('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```
````

Comment: Please accept this as an answer if you find it as you wanted.

Comment: It's the correct answer, although I was looking for a pop-up that would also stay up after the user has pressed buttons or changed values in it. The dialog box allows that, because it only closes after pressing OK. It's just that the OK button is annoyingly large...